# x-based y phrasing descriptions

Tags: description

I am trying to find the proper way to describe the following: outcome-based benchmarking, outcome-based contracting, outcome-based designs, performance-based education, performance-based management, performance-based financing, etc... The general form is x-based y; however, I am looking for what I should generally call the x-variable and what I should call the y-variable and if there is a concept that describes the entire thing.